# Regex to match string ending with string or nothing

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match strings ending with javascript encoded characters *(%20, %u200E, etc)* or end of line.

I've got this regex: `(/\w*?)*(?=(%\w{2,}|[\s/]))` which matches `/text` part in these:

> /text
>   /text
>   /text%20
>   /text%u200E

But doesn't matches anything in this: `/text` *(no character at end, not even new line)*

Comment: `$` = end of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
/(?:\/\w*)*(?=(?:%\w{2,})|[\s/]|$)/;
```

Since you don't have newline `\n` at the end of your inputs. Just end of input anchor `$` will do the job.

Comment: wow, I was so sure I tried this too, can't believe it was so easy, thank you